# How to filter/find records in MongoDB based on Date

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection in MongoDB database that has some data and would like to filter and find data based on date (ignoring time).

**Sample Data**

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("563a38173c2ab9248c02d89e"),
  "jobId" : "oAEKMcCIJRIAAAFQbrAR6NDd",
  "jobName" : "CheckSessions",
  "jobDesc" : "Checks and deletes expired session data",
  "jobType" : "Job",
  "startTime" : "2015-11-04 00:00:01",
  "endTime" : "2015-11-04 00:00:01",
  "domainName" : "root",
  "recurrencePeriod" : "60",
  "recurrencePeriodDesc" : "HOURS(1)"
}
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("563a38173c2ab9248c02d89f"),
  "jobId" : "C6wKMcCIJXoAAAFQm78R6NCm",
  "jobName" : "CheckSessions",
  "jobDesc" : "Checks and deletes expired session data",
  "jobType" : "Job",
  "startTime" : "2015-11-03 23:00:00",
  "endTime" : "2015-11-03 23:00:01",
  "domainName" : "root",
  "recurrencePeriod" : "60",
  "recurrencePeriodDesc" : "HOURS(1)"
}
```

I used the following command to fetch data greater than a specific date but it did not give me any results. Both startTime and endTime are in EST format. Not sure what am I missing. Please guide.

```
db.jobs.find({"startTime" : { $gt : new Date("2015-11-03")}});
```

Comment: How did you save `startTime` and `endTime`? I think you saved them as strings, so Mongo does not understand that they are dates. You can use simple string comparison with something like: `{"startTime" : { $gt : "2015-11-03"}}`

Comment: I got a hint from the above-mentioned comment. thanks, buddy

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Answer: You can query simply by string comparison.

> First, ensure index on startTime column

```
db.test.ensureIndex({startTime:1})
```

Following command finds you second object in the example with `_id:ObjectId("563a38173c2ab9248c02d89f")`

```
db.test.find({
    startTime: {
        $gte: '2015-11-03 00:00:00',
        $lt:  '2015-11-04 00:00:00'
    }
}).pretty()
```

By running explain() on our query, we can see the index is in fact in use:

```
db.test.find({startTime:{$gte:'2015-11-03 00:00:00', $lt:'2015-11-04 00:00:00'}}).explain()

{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor startTime_1",
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "n" : 1,
    "nscannedObjects" : 1,
    "nscanned" : 1,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 1,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 1,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 0,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 0,
    "indexBounds" : {
        "startTime" : [
            [
                "2015-11-03 00:00:00",
                "2015-11-04 00:00:00"
            ]
        ]
    },
    "server" : "Jaans-MBP.home:27017"
}
```

My recommendation still is to **follow best practices and to store your date fields in proper date format**, e.g.

```
"startTime" : ISODate("2016-05-02T00:00:02Z")
```

in MongoDB shell you'd simply pass

```
> db.test.insert({startTime:new Date()})
> db.test.find()
// results
{ "_id" : ObjectId("563a49d63b1f1b7df0ebc4f5"), "startTime" : ISODate("2015-11-04T18:09:26.613Z") }
```

Comment: Thanks, and good to know about the best practice but the data getting stored here comes from some other table hence the date format is little different here (EST format to be precise). How can I find records using this specific date format ? Please guide.

Comment: @dgiugg provided pretty accurate idea how to search (assuming you have indexes in place). Use $gte:"2015-01-01 00:00:00" and you should be fine. I'll test later to confirm it.

Comment: Updated ... and hope it helps.

Comment: So even if we store dates as strings mongodb will give correct results ?